# How To Fix Error no 2013 in sqlYog

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I know this question has asked serveral times but I'm not been able to solve sorry for asking. I'm connecting localhost database to my webserver database from sqlyog now I'm getting error 2013 in sqlyog.

This is how I'm trying to access the webserver database from sqlyog but now I'm getting error no.2013.

```
mysql host address:- 139......... // the ip address
mysql username    :- abcxyz_co    // username of mysql db
mysql password    :- hello        // mysql database password
port              :3306           // this is the default sqlyog port i have also used port 2082
mysql database    :- xyzdatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

Before installing SQYog, first install the MySQl in your system.

Use this link :- https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

After successful installation of MySql and configure it remember the password, then try to run the SQLYog use the same password you use to configure MySql.

It worked for me